# How to run d3 Javascript in MAMP local server

Tags: javascript, json, apache, d3.js, mamp

I am trying to run these two files that are for visualising a graph in d3 Javascript library:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<style>

  .node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }

 .link {
 stroke: #999;
 stroke-opacity: .6;
 }

 </style>
 <body>
 <p> I am there </p>
 <script src="d3.v3.js"></script>
 <script src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>
 <script>

  var width = 960,
  height = 500;

  var color = d3.scale.category20();

  var force = d3.layout.force()
 .charge(-120)
 .linkDistance(30)
 .size([width, height]);

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height);

 d3.json("miserables.json", function(error, graph) {
 force
  .nodes(graph.nodes)
  .links(graph.links)
  .start();

 var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
  .data(graph.links)
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

 var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
  .call(force.drag);

 node.append("title")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

 force.on("tick", function() {
 link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
     .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
     .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
     .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
});
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the json file called: `miserables.json`

```
{
"nodes":[
{"name":"Myriel","group":1},
{"name":"Napoleon","group":1},
{"name":"Mlle.Baptistine","group":1},
{"name":"Mme.Magloire","group":1},
{"name":"CountessdeLo","group":1},
{"name":"Geborand","group":1},
{"name":"Champtercier","group":1},
{"name":"Cravatte","group":1},
{"name":"Count","group":1},
{"name":"OldMan","group":1},
{"name":"Labarre","group":2},
{"name":"Valjean","group":2},
{"name":"Marguerite","group":3},
{"name":"Mme.deR","group":2},
{"name":"Isabeau","group":2},
{"name":"Gervais","group":2},
{"name":"Tholomyes","group":3},
{"name":"Listolier","group":3},
{"name":"Fameuil","group":3},
{"name":"Blacheville","group":3},
{"name":"Favourite","group":3},
{"name":"Dahlia","group":3},
{"name":"Zephine","group":3},
{"name":"Fantine","group":3},
{"name":"Mme.Thenardier","group":4},
{"name":"Thenardier","group":4},
{"name":"Cosette","group":5},
{"name":"Javert","group":4},
{"name":"Fauchelevent","group":0},
{"name":"Bamatabois","group":2},
{"name":"Perpetue","group":3},
{"name":"Simplice","group":2},
{"name":"Scaufflaire","group":2},
{"name":"Woman1","group":2},
{"name":"Judge","group":2},
{"name":"Champmathieu","group":2},
{"name":"Brevet","group":2},
{"name":"Chenildieu","group":2},
{"name":"Cochepaille","group":2},
{"name":"Pontmercy","group":4},
{"name":"Boulatruelle","group":6},
{"name":"Eponine","group":4},
{"name":"Anzelma","group":4},
{"name":"Woman2","group":5},
{"name":"MotherInnocent","group":0},
{"name":"Gribier","group":0},
{"name":"Jondrette","group":7},
{"name":"Mme.Burgon","group":7},
{"name":"Gavroche","group":8},
{"name":"Gillenormand","group":5},
{"name":"Magnon","group":5},
{"name":"Mlle.Gillenormand","group":5},
{"name":"Mme.Pontmercy","group":5},
{"name":"Mlle.Vaubois","group":5},
{"name":"Lt.Gillenormand","group":5},
{"name":"Marius","group":8},
{"name":"BaronessT","group":5},
{"name":"Mabeuf","group":8},
{"name":"Enjolras","group":8},
{"name":"Combeferre","group":8},
{"name":"Prouvaire","group":8},
{"name":"Feuilly","group":8},
{"name":"Courfeyrac","group":8},
{"name":"Bahorel","group":8},
{"name":"Bossuet","group":8},
{"name":"Joly","group":8},
{"name":"Grantaire","group":8},
{"name":"MotherPlutarch","group":9},
{"name":"Gueulemer","group":4},
{"name":"Babet","group":4},
{"name":"Claquesous","group":4},
{"name":"Montparnasse","group":4},
{"name":"Toussaint","group":5},
{"name":"Child1","group":10},
{"name":"Child2","group":10},
{"name":"Brujon","group":4},
{"name":"Mme.Hucheloup","group":8}
],
"links":[
{"source":1,"target":0,"value":1},
{"source":2,"target":0,"value":8},
{"source":3,"target":0,"value":10},
{"source":3,"target":2,"value":6},
{"source":4,"target":0,"value":1},
{"source":5,"target":0,"value":1},
{"source":6,"target":0,"value":1},
{"source":7,"target":0,"value":1},
{"source":8,"target":0,"value":2},
{"source":9,"target":0,"value":1},
{"source":11,"target":10,"value":1},
{"source":11,"target":3,"value":3},
{"source":11,"target":2,"value":3},
{"source":11,"target":0,"value":5},
{"source":12,"target":11,"value":1},
{"source":13,"target":11,"value":1},
{"source":14,"target":11,"value":1},
{"source":15,"target":11,"value":1},
{"source":17,"target":16,"value":4},
{"source":18,"target":16,"value":4},
{"source":18,"target":17,"value":4},
{"source":19,"target":16,"value":4},
{"source":19,"target":17,"value":4},
{"source":19,"target":18,"value":4},
{"source":20,"target":16,"value":3},
{"source":20,"target":17,"value":3},
{"source":20,"target":18,"value":3},
{"source":20,"target":19,"value":4},
{"source":21,"target":16,"value":3},
{"source":21,"target":17,"value":3},
{"source":21,"target":18,"value":3},
{"source":21,"target":19,"value":3},
{"source":21,"target":20,"value":5},
{"source":22,"target":16,"value":3},
{"source":22,"target":17,"value":3},
{"source":22,"target":18,"value":3},
{"source":22,"target":19,"value":3},
{"source":22,"target":20,"value":4},
{"source":22,"target":21,"value":4},
{"source":23,"target":16,"value":3},
{"source":23,"target":17,"value":3},
{"source":23,"target":18,"value":3},
{"source":23,"target":19,"value":3},
{"source":23,"target":20,"value":4},
{"source":23,"target":21,"value":4},
{"source":23,"target":22,"value":4},
{"source":23,"target":12,"value":2},
{"source":23,"target":11,"value":9},
{"source":24,"target":23,"value":2},
{"source":24,"target":11,"value":7},
{"source":25,"target":24,"value":13},
{"source":25,"target":23,"value":1},
{"source":25,"target":11,"value":12},
{"source":26,"target":24,"value":4},
{"source":26,"target":11,"value":31},
{"source":26,"target":16,"value":1},
{"source":26,"target":25,"value":1},
{"source":27,"target":11,"value":17},
{"source":27,"target":23,"value":5},
{"source":27,"target":25,"value":5},
{"source":27,"target":24,"value":1},
{"source":27,"target":26,"value":1},
{"source":28,"target":11,"value":8},
{"source":28,"target":27,"value":1},
{"source":29,"target":23,"value":1},
{"source":29,"target":27,"value":1},
{"source":29,"target":11,"value":2},
{"source":30,"target":23,"value":1},
{"source":31,"target":30,"value":2},
{"source":31,"target":11,"value":3},
{"source":31,"target":23,"value":2},
{"source":31,"target":27,"value":1},
{"source":32,"target":11,"value":1},
{"source":33,"target":11,"value":2},
{"source":33,"target":27,"value":1},
{"source":34,"target":11,"value":3},
{"source":34,"target":29,"value":2},
{"source":35,"target":11,"value":3},
{"source":35,"target":34,"value":3},
{"source":35,"target":29,"value":2},
{"source":36,"target":34,"value":2},
{"source":36,"target":35,"value":2},
{"source":36,"target":11,"value":2},
{"source":36,"target":29,"value":1},
{"source":37,"target":34,"value":2},
{"source":37,"target":35,"value":2},
{"source":37,"target":36,"value":2},
{"source":37,"target":11,"value":2},
{"source":37,"target":29,"value":1},
{"source":38,"target":34,"value":2},
{"source":38,"target":35,"value":2},
{"source":38,"target":36,"value":2},
{"source":38,"target":37,"value":2},
{"source":38,"target":11,"value":2},
{"source":38,"target":29,"value":1},
{"source":39,"target":25,"value":1},
{"source":40,"target":25,"value":1},
{"source":41,"target":24,"value":2},
{"source":41,"target":25,"value":3},
{"source":42,"target":41,"value":2},
{"source":42,"target":25,"value":2},
{"source":42,"target":24,"value":1},
{"source":43,"target":11,"value":3},
{"source":43,"target":26,"value":1},
{"source":43,"target":27,"value":1},
{"source":44,"target":28,"value":3},
{"source":44,"target":11,"value":1},
{"source":45,"target":28,"value":2},
{"source":47,"target":46,"value":1},
{"source":48,"target":47,"value":2},
{"source":48,"target":25,"value":1},
{"source":48,"target":27,"value":1},
{"source":48,"target":11,"value":1},
{"source":49,"target":26,"value":3},
{"source":49,"target":11,"value":2},
{"source":50,"target":49,"value":1},
{"source":50,"target":24,"value":1},
{"source":51,"target":49,"value":9},
{"source":51,"target":26,"value":2},
{"source":51,"target":11,"value":2},
{"source":52,"target":51,"value":1},
{"source":52,"target":39,"value":1},
{"source":53,"target":51,"value":1},
{"source":54,"target":51,"value":2},
{"source":54,"target":49,"value":1},
{"source":54,"target":26,"value":1},
{"source":55,"target":51,"value":6},
{"source":55,"target":49,"value":12},
{"source":55,"target":39,"value":1},
{"source":55,"target":54,"value":1},
{"source":55,"target":26,"value":21},
{"source":55,"target":11,"value":19},
{"source":55,"target":16,"value":1},
{"source":55,"target":25,"value":2},
{"source":55,"target":41,"value":5},
{"source":55,"target":48,"value":4},
{"source":56,"target":49,"value":1},
{"source":56,"target":55,"value":1},
{"source":57,"target":55,"value":1},
{"source":57,"target":41,"value":1},
{"source":57,"target":48,"value":1},
{"source":58,"target":55,"value":7},
{"source":58,"target":48,"value":7},
{"source":58,"target":27,"value":6},
{"source":58,"target":57,"value":1},
{"source":58,"target":11,"value":4},
{"source":59,"target":58,"value":15},
{"source":59,"target":55,"value":5},
{"source":59,"target":48,"value":6},
{"source":59,"target":57,"value":2},
{"source":60,"target":48,"value":1},
{"source":60,"target":58,"value":4},
{"source":60,"target":59,"value":2},
{"source":61,"target":48,"value":2},
{"source":61,"target":58,"value":6},
{"source":61,"target":60,"value":2},
{"source":61,"target":59,"value":5},
{"source":61,"target":57,"value":1},
{"source":61,"target":55,"value":1},
{"source":62,"target":55,"value":9},
{"source":62,"target":58,"value":17},
{"source":62,"target":59,"value":13},
{"source":62,"target":48,"value":7},
{"source":62,"target":57,"value":2},
{"source":62,"target":41,"value":1},
{"source":62,"target":61,"value":6},
{"source":62,"target":60,"value":3},
{"source":63,"target":59,"value":5},
{"source":63,"target":48,"value":5},
{"source":63,"target":62,"value":6},
{"source":63,"target":57,"value":2},
{"source":63,"target":58,"value":4},
{"source":63,"target":61,"value":3},
{"source":63,"target":60,"value":2},
{"source":63,"target":55,"value":1},
{"source":64,"target":55,"value":5},
{"source":64,"target":62,"value":12},
{"source":64,"target":48,"value":5},
{"source":64,"target":63,"value":4},
{"source":64,"target":58,"value":10},
{"source":64,"target":61,"value":6},
{"source":64,"target":60,"value":2},
{"source":64,"target":59,"value":9},
{"source":64,"target":57,"value":1},
{"source":64,"target":11,"value":1},
{"source":65,"target":63,"value":5},
{"source":65,"target":64,"value":7},
{"source":65,"target":48,"value":3},
{"source":65,"target":62,"value":5},
{"source":65,"target":58,"value":5},
{"source":65,"target":61,"value":5},
{"source":65,"target":60,"value":2},
{"source":65,"target":59,"value":5},
{"source":65,"target":57,"value":1},
{"source":65,"target":55,"value":2},
{"source":66,"target":64,"value":3},
{"source":66,"target":58,"value":3},
{"source":66,"target":59,"value":1},
{"source":66,"target":62,"value":2},
{"source":66,"target":65,"value":2},
{"source":66,"target":48,"value":1},
{"source":66,"target":63,"value":1},
{"source":66,"target":61,"value":1},
{"source":66,"target":60,"value":1},
{"source":67,"target":57,"value":3},
{"source":68,"target":25,"value":5},
{"source":68,"target":11,"value":1},
{"source":68,"target":24,"value":1},
{"source":68,"target":27,"value":1},
{"source":68,"target":48,"value":1},
{"source":68,"target":41,"value":1},
{"source":69,"target":25,"value":6},
{"source":69,"target":68,"value":6},
{"source":69,"target":11,"value":1},
{"source":69,"target":24,"value":1},
{"source":69,"target":27,"value":2},
{"source":69,"target":48,"value":1},
{"source":69,"target":41,"value":1},
{"source":70,"target":25,"value":4},
{"source":70,"target":69,"value":4},
{"source":70,"target":68,"value":4},
{"source":70,"target":11,"value":1},
{"source":70,"target":24,"value":1},
{"source":70,"target":27,"value":1},
{"source":70,"target":41,"value":1},
{"source":70,"target":58,"value":1},
{"source":71,"target":27,"value":1},
{"source":71,"target":69,"value":2},
{"source":71,"target":68,"value":2},
{"source":71,"target":70,"value":2},
{"source":71,"target":11,"value":1},
{"source":71,"target":48,"value":1},
{"source":71,"target":41,"value":1},
{"source":71,"target":25,"value":1},
{"source":72,"target":26,"value":2},
{"source":72,"target":27,"value":1},
{"source":72,"target":11,"value":1},
{"source":73,"target":48,"value":2},
{"source":74,"target":48,"value":2},
{"source":74,"target":73,"value":3},
{"source":75,"target":69,"value":3},
{"source":75,"target":68,"value":3},
{"source":75,"target":25,"value":3},
{"source":75,"target":48,"value":1},
{"source":75,"target":41,"value":1},
{"source":75,"target":70,"value":1},
{"source":75,"target":71,"value":1},
{"source":76,"target":64,"value":1},
{"source":76,"target":65,"value":1},
{"source":76,"target":66,"value":1},
{"source":76,"target":63,"value":1},
{"source":76,"target":62,"value":1},
{"source":76,"target":48,"value":1},
{"source":76,"target":58,"value":1}
]
}
```

I have installed MAMP for mac 10.5.8 to run these two files. Inside the folder where MAMP is located in my system, there is a folder called `htdocs`. I created a folder inside `htdocs` and named it: `sample` and added these two files inside `sample` . I also added the files: `d3.v3.js` and `d3.v3.min.js`. After I started the MAMP local server, I inserted into the Web Browser `http://localhost:8888/sample/`. Unfortunately, the graph is not displayed. I think there is a problem either with reading json file :`miserables.json` or the javascript file: `d3.v3.js`. Could anyone please help me with this issue as I do not know why the graph is not displayed. Your help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Where are your `<html>` and `<head>` tags?

Comment: Sorry about that, I have edited the file.

Comment: Do you have any message in your console log? And there is no need to include both d3.v3.js and minified version d3.v3.min.js.

Comment: I have deleted d3.v3.min.js. I do not have any console log messages. I have added one line of paragraph as you can see in the code above and it appeared. I cant understand why the graph itself is not displayed. I am guessing the problem either reading the JSON file or the d3.v3.js. Do you have any idea?

Comment: With your code and json file (cut&paste) I got force graph immediately. So something is wrong with your configuration. If I disable wamp server I got, for example, message: _XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/wamp/www/D3-Examples/miserables.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. force.html:1_  So your code is fine for sure.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Would you recommend me anything for this issue? If I disable the MAMP server, It shows me this message: [Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8888]. Do you have any idea how I can solve this please?

Comment: I would try to get dummy html page running on MAMP server. No d3, no json, just to get some message out. And then preceed with d3 example. Check docs of MAMP, maybe you get some hints. Sorry, I'm not the expert...

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely encountering a CORS issue with the XHR in the d3 library for an external resource to parse the JSON data.

One solution to running d3 locally is to lose MAMP, rather use JSONP and Express/Node.js in conjunction with a jQuery function to initiate a client-side request for JSON, instead of using the original wrapper for d3 functions.

Had to remove the original d3.json wrapper and populate the adjacency diagrams with data from the request. Begin by cloning or downloading [jsonp-d3-experiment](https://github.com/jchristianhall/jsonp-d3-experiment) and start the server using `node server.js`. Of course you need to have Node.js installed globally, beginning with Node Packaged Modules (npm). Copy your program into a subdirectory.

Below is the code I modified for a co-occurrence matrix. I moved the entire script into `$.getJSON` and removed the `d3.json` function altogether.

```
<script>
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/data?callback=?", function(result){

      miserables = result;

      var margin = {
          top: 80,
          right: 0,
          bottom: 10,
          left: 80
        },
        width = 720,
        height = 720;

      var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeBands([0, width]),
        z = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 4]).clamp(true),
        c = d3.scale.category10().domain(d3.range(10));

      var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .style("margin-left", -margin.left + "px")
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


        var matrix = [],
          nodes = miserables.nodes,
          n = nodes.length;

        // Compute index per node.
        nodes.forEach(function(node, i) {
          node.index = i;
          node.count = 0;
          matrix[i] = d3.range(n).map(function(j) {
            return {
              x: j,
              y: i,
              z: 0
            };
          });
        });

        // Convert links to matrix; count character occurrences.
        miserables.links.forEach(function(link) {
          matrix[link.source][link.target].z += link.value;
          matrix[link.target][link.source].z += link.value;
          matrix[link.source][link.source].z += link.value;
          matrix[link.target][link.target].z += link.value;
          nodes[link.source].count += link.value;
          nodes[link.target].count += link.value;
        });

        // Precompute the orders.
        var orders = {
          name: d3.range(n).sort(function(a, b) {
            return d3.ascending(nodes[a].name, nodes[b].name);
          }),
          count: d3.range(n).sort(function(a, b) {
            return nodes[b].count - nodes[a].count;
          }),
          group: d3.range(n).sort(function(a, b) {
            return nodes[b].group - nodes[a].group;
          })
        };

        // The default sort order.
        x.domain(orders.name);

        svg.append("rect")
          .attr("class", "background")
          .attr("width", width)
          .attr("height", height);

        var row = svg.selectAll(".row")
          .data(matrix)
          .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "row")
          .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
            return "translate(0," + x(i) + ")";
          })
          .each(row);

        row.append("line")
          .attr("x2", width);

        row.append("text")
          .attr("x", -6)
          .attr("y", x.rangeBand() / 2)
          .attr("dy", ".32em")
          .attr("text-anchor", "end")
          .text(function(d, i) {
            return nodes[i].name;
          });

        var column = svg.selectAll(".column")
          .data(matrix)
          .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "column")
          .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
            return "translate(" + x(i) + ")rotate(-90)";
          });

        column.append("line")
          .attr("x1", -width);

        column.append("text")
          .attr("x", 6)
          .attr("y", x.rangeBand() / 2)
          .attr("dy", ".32em")
          .attr("text-anchor", "start")
          .text(function(d, i) {
            return nodes[i].name;
          });

        function row(row) {
          var cell = d3.select(this).selectAll(".cell")
            .data(row.filter(function(d) {
              return d.z;
            }))
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("class", "cell")
            .attr("x", function(d) {
              return x(d.x);
            })
            .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
            .attr("height", x.rangeBand())
            .style("fill-opacity", function(d) {
              return z(d.z);
            })
            .style("fill", function(d) {
              return nodes[d.x].group == nodes[d.y].group ? c(nodes[d.x].group) : null;
            })
            .on("mouseover", mouseover)
            .on("mouseout", mouseout);
        }

        function mouseover(p) {
          d3.selectAll(".row text").classed("active", function(d, i) {
            return i == p.y;
          });
          d3.selectAll(".column text").classed("active", function(d, i) {
            return i == p.x;
          });
        }

        function mouseout() {
          d3.selectAll("text").classed("active", false);
        }

        d3.select("#order").on("change", function() {
          clearTimeout(timeout);
          order(this.value);
        });

        function order(value) {
          x.domain(orders[value]);

          var t = svg.transition().duration(2500);

          t.selectAll(".row")
            .delay(function(d, i) {
              return x(i) * 4;
            })
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              return "translate(0," + x(i) + ")";
            })
            .selectAll(".cell")
            .delay(function(d) {
              return x(d.x) * 4;
            })
            .attr("x", function(d) {
              return x(d.x);
            });

          t.selectAll(".column")
            .delay(function(d, i) {
              return x(i) * 4;
            })
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              return "translate(" + x(i) + ")rotate(-90)";
            });
        }

        var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
          order("group");
          d3.select("#order").property("selectedIndex", 2).node().focus();
        }, 5000);
      });
</script>
```

Notice that now the JSON data is in `result`, so the easiest thing to do was to assign it to `miserables`.

Use CDN or local copies to include d3 (which I don't see in your example) and jQuery which is required for this solution.

Now you should be able to locally open and render all your d3 visualizations without hosting them on a server--simply open them in your browser straight from your local filesystem.

HTH!